# In .NET Aspire, how to get the resolved endpoint to create a Link

Tags: c#, dotnet-aspire

Using the new [.NET Aspire](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-dotnet-aspire-simplifying-cloud-native-development-with-dotnet-8/)
Let's explore a scenario involving two web apps: the main app, and the login app:

```
var login = builder.AddProject<Projects.LoginApp_Web>("login");

builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireApp_Web>("main-app")
    .WithReference(login); // not sure if will be need it
```

Questions:

1. Main App Endpoint to Login App: In the main-app, specifically on a Razor page, how can we create an endpoint that directs users to the login app?
2. Furthermore, Two-Way Navigation, Is it possible to establish a two-way link between the main app and the login app? For instance, can the main app provide a link to the login app, and vice versa, How would we achieve this?

It seems the [ServiceDiscovery](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/tree/8b008aabc9e31a06c50a025978c5d977c5e7ba20/src/aspire/src/Microsoft.Extensions.ServiceDiscovery) is the responsible for that, but I am not able to figure it out how to use it.

Comment: I hope you already checked the new eshop https://github.com/dotnet/eShop/blob/main/src/eShop.AppHost/Program.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @AkalankaDissanayake,

1. Do not need `.WithReference(login);` instead need to get `http` or `https` url and save it in app Environment.

```
mainApp.WithEnvironment("LoginUrl", login.GetEndpoint("http"));

// Similarly you can do the other way around as well.
login.WithEnvironment("mainAppUrl", mainApp.GetEndpoint("http"));
```

2. Now this value can be access by the configuration

```
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
configuration.GetRequiredValue("LoginUrl");

// which get the value from here:
configuration[name]
```

Original code:

- https://github.com/dotnet/eShop/blob/main/src/eShop.AppHost/Program.cs
- https://github.com/dotnet/eShop/blob/main/src/WebApp/Extensions/Extensions.cs
- https://github.com/dotnet/eShop/blob/main/src/eShop.ServiceDefaults/ConfigurationExtensions.cs